# topology over $X$

Tags: general-topology

**Definition. A topology $\tau$ is a collection of open X such that:**

(i) $\emptyset$ and $X \in \tau$;

(ii) arbitrary union of $A$ open is opened;

(iii) finite intersection of open is opened.

**To prove that the union of topologies is a topology this stems from the topology axiomas, because:**

(i) $\emptyset$ and $X\in \cap C$, because $\emptyset$ and $X$ belongs to each topology, so it belongs to the intersection.

(ii) arbitrary intersection of finite intersection is opened. How to prove this fact?

(iii) arbitrary intersection of arbitrary union is opened.How to prove this fact?

**Already for the union arbitraria, have:  What's the flaw?**

(i) $\emptyset$ and $X\in \cap C$, because $\emptyset$ and $X$ belongs to each topology, so it belongs to the union.

(ii) arbitrary union of finite intersection is opened. How to prove this fact?

(iii) arbitrary union of arbitrary union is opened. How to prove this fact?

Can someone help me please?

Comment: What's your definition of open sets?

Comment: The elements of the topology

Comment: Then how can you use open sets to define topologies?

Comment: @Yourong'DZR'Zang: Completely obvious in context.

Comment: @Yourong'DZR'Zang: She’s not; she just hasn’t written the definition of a topology very clearly. It should say that a topology on $X$ is a family of subsets of $X$, called open sets, with the three listed properties.

Comment: The OP clearly refers to open sets in the definition.

Comment: @Yourong'DZR'Zang: And English is clearly not her first language, so you need to exercise a little common sense when reading it.

Comment: For finite intersection, take $U_1$ from $T_1$, and $U_2$ from $T_2$.  There's nothing we can say about $U_1 \cap U_2$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott my point is if the OP is writing it more clearly the answer will appear immediately

Comment: @Yourong'DZR'Zang: Having watched several of her earlier questions, I see no reason to think so.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott And I did not see why the OP's language skills matter here. The OP's question is very clear.

Comment: @Yourong'DZR'Zang: The question is clear enough that there was no reason for *your* original question.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I cannot understand your criticism. I tried to give the OP a hint. Maybe it's a bad hint. But it's definitely not a wrong hint.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott And instead of pointing out my problems, you should try to give the OP some ideas or hints. That would be way more helpful and constructive.

Comment: @Yourong: I don't think the answer appears immediately just by writing out the statement more clearly. It took me most of the time you and Brian have spent arguing about the question to come up with the counter-example in my answer.

Comment: @RobArthan True. I admit my hint was bad or even useless. But I still could not understand why my bad hints were criticized because of the OP's language problem.

Answer (score 3):

The part about $\bigcap C$ being a topology is not too difficult if you write out the definitions and follow your way through.

For an example where $\bigcup C$ is not a topology, take $C = \{\tau_1, \tau_2\}$ where $\tau_i$ comprises all the subsets of $\{1, 2, 3\}$ that are either empty or contain $i$. Then $\{3\} = \{1, 3\} \cap \{2, 3\} \not\in \bigcup C$, but it would have to be if $\bigcup C$ were a topology.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that $\mathscr{C}$ is a family of topologies on $X$. Let $\tau_0=\bigcap\mathscr{C}$. You showed that $\varnothing,X\in\tau_0$. To show that $\tau$ is closed under taking arbitrary unions, let $\mathscr{U}\subseteq\tau$; we want to show that $U\in\tau_0$. Let $\tau\in\mathscr{C}$; then $\mathscr{U}\subseteq\tau_0\subseteq\tau$, so $\mathscr{U}\subseteq\tau$. And $\tau$ is a topology, so $\bigcup\mathscr{U}\in\tau$. Thus, $\bigcup\mathscr{U}\in\tau$ for each $\tau\in\mathscr{C}$, and therefore

$$\bigcup\mathscr{U}\in\bigcap\mathscr{C}=\tau_0\,,$$

as desired.

The proof that $\tau_0$ is closed under taking finite intersections is very similar; see if you can carry it out using this as a model.

To show that $\bigcup\mathscr{C}$ is not necessarily a topology on $X$, you need to produce a counterexample: you want a set $X$ and a family of topologies on $X$ whose union is not a topology on $X$. You can actually do this with just a pair of topologies, say $\tau_1$ and $\tau_2$ on a small set.

- Try to find topologies $\tau_1$ and $\tau_2$ on $X=\{0,1,2\}$ such that there are sets $U_1\in\tau_1$ and $U_2\in\tau_2$ whose intersection is not in $\tau_1\cup\tau_2$; this will show that $\tau_1\cup\tau_2$ is not a topology on $X$.

Comment: A great, concise answer.

Comment: Okay, thank you!!!!

Comment: @Yourong'DZR'Zang: I was probably a bit too abrupt in my earlier comments; I’d just been arguing with someone on another site, and I’m afraid that the mood carried over a bit!

Comment: @IsadoraSuhadolnick: You’re welcome!